# IE11 width: 100% and max-width: 300px; on an element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with the following markup/styling in IE11:

```css
main{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<main><p>lorem</p></main>
```

The problem is that the max-width is not respected in IE11.

It works as expected in < IE11, IE11 with the new spartan engine and all other browsers.

Comment: Guess You'd better go to https://connect.microsoft.com/ to report the bug.
and change question if you'd like to achieve it in another way.

Comment: what doctype are you using? according to mdn *This property is enabled only under the strict !DOCTYPE.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not yet have `display:block` in its browser stylesheet for the `main` element – adding it in your own stylesheet should fix the issue.

```
main {
  display:block;
  /* rest of your properties */
}
```